# How does one send an email after the submission job is done in condor?

Tags: condor

I was trying to use the email option after running a condor job. I tried this:

```
Executable   = executable.sh
Log          = file.log
Output       = file.stdout
Error        = file.stderr
# Use this to make sure 1 gpu is available. The key words are case insensitive. 
REquest_gpus = 1
# Note: to use multiple CPUs instead of the default (one CPU), use request_cpus as well
Request_cpus = 3
# "Queue" means add the setup until this line to the queue.
Queue
#
Notify_user = my_email@yahoo.com
```

but it failed. Why? How do I put it in the submission file?

---

This didn't help either:

```
notify_user = $<$email-address$>$
Used to specify the e-mail address to use when Condor sends e-mail about a job. If not specified, Condor defaults to using the e-mail address defined by
job-owner@UID_DOMAIN
where the configuration variable UID_DOMAIN is specified by the Condor site administrator. If UID_DOMAIN has not been specified, Condor sends the e-mail to:
job-owner@submit-machine-name
```

https://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/manual/v7.6/condor_submit.html

regardless I want it in the `job.sub` script regardless.

---

## Edit:

I put the notify user at the end. Now I do not see errors in the condor logs but I am not receiving an e-mail. So it means condor parsed my filed correctly after having `Queue` be at the end but it's not sending emails. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In an HTCondor submit file, the "Queue" statement should also be the last thing in the file.  Try moving the Queue to the end, so that the notify_user is somewhere before it in the file.

Also, you'll want a notification = always in the submit file, like this

```
 notify_user = my_email@example.com
 notification = always
```

Comment: Ok I don't get an error anymore but it seems that I am not receiving my e-mails for some reason. Did you try it out yourself? Did it work for you?

Comment: Could be a couple of things.  You'll want a

    notification = always

in the submit file somewhere before the queue statement.

If that doesn't work, and assuming you are on a linux machine, the admin may be blocking email.  Let's hope it is the first one...

Comment: how do I try that first one greg? Whats the syntax?

Comment: stack overflow comments make the code formatting a little difficult, but on the line in your submit file where you have notify_user = your_email, put a new line above that that says notification = always

Comment: I changed my mind and only want condor to send me e-mails when there are errors my submission script cannot catch. What is the option for email on errors? Btw, where are you looking these things up? I have not found a good way to get info about condor online or otherwise...

Comment: Well, you can change the line from notification = always to notification = error. This means to only send email if the job exits with a non-zero error code.